# How can I create and display JSp Template as PDF

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot, servlets

I have a requirement in which I have to generate PDF. That PDf we can display in full browser or we can display it inside iframe as a preview. I want to create one JSP template using HTML and JSP with some dynamic data. Whenever I click on generate pfd I want this template to come in iFrame as a pdf. What should I do and how can I convert dynamic jsp into pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is use `org.apache.pdfbox`.

See for more info and many exsamples https://pdfbox.apache.org/

When the user clicks the generate button, you will need the create the pdf step by step so that it looks like the template. You can't "copy" a part of the jsp template including data straight to the pdf.

You can create the output as a file or as a byte array:

```
protected void create(Object model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = createTemporaryOutputStream();

    PDDocument document = newDocument();

    // Build PDF document.
    buildPdfDocument(model, document, request, response);
    document.save(baos);
    document.close();


    final String filename = "pdf-as-byte-stream.pdf";

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    writeToResponse(response, baos);
}
```

With above solution the pdf with be displayed in the browser full screen.
But because you want to show it as an iframe you need to save the byte stream to a file and then point the iframe to that file.

```
<iframe src="https://www.yoursite.com/pdf/dgxedg37gd3wedb3d83vd3dgv3dt3.pdf"></iframe>
```

(Make sure you generate a unique name for the pdf)